# print column to many row awk

Tags: awk, split, row, csh

i stuck at this problem for a long time. i have a input file with many line like this

```
<594711>
<name>
<duyduy>
<SV>
<RUN>
<AL_Ptime>
</common/sAS>
<lsf_login07>
</shsv/DASA>
<594712>
<name>
<thanhthanh>
<SV>
<RUN>
<AL_Ptime>
</common/NDWQ>
<lsf_login07>
</shsv/CXZC>
```

my desire it split it to row like this. It repeat after job ID

```
<594711> <RUN> <AL_Ptime> <lsf_login07> </shsv/DASA>
<594712> <RUN> <AL_Ptime> <lsf_login07> </shsv/CXZC>
```

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: i even don't know what command to get it
i got the input from code grep -oE '<[^>]+>' file.
i think about using Paste -s but it seem like doesn't work as well

Comment: How come `lsf_login07` came in 2nd row, it is not present in second set of `<594712>`?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 sorry i forget to type it
don't mind it bro
i edited it

Comment: @AlecFenichel here sir this is my whole script and i stuck at this session. I read doc and can't find the right command to solve it
#!/bin/csh -f
rm -rf result120
rm -rf result124
rm -rf result126
foreach file ( `cat aaa` )
        echo `bjobs -l $file >> result120`
        echo ""
end
awk '{\
gsub(/                     /,"",$0)}\
BEGIN {\
RS =""\
FS=","\
}\
{\
if ($1 ~/Job/){\
print $1 $2 $3 $4 $5 $6 $7 $8 $9 $10 $11 $12 $13 $14 $15 $16}\
}' result120 > result126
grep -oE '<[^>]+>' result126 > result125

Comment: @Lucil120, np, check my solution on same now. And please don't post your tries in comments, post in your POST itself so that could be visible to all then. Enjoy learning !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following `awk` code may help you in same.

```
awk '
/<\/shsv\/[a-zA-Z]+>/{
  val=val?val OFS $0:$0;
  print val;
  flag="";
  next
}
/<[0-9]+>/{
  flag=1;
  val=$0;
  next
}
val && (($0 ~ /<RUN>/) || ($0 ~ /<AL_Ptime>/) || ($0 ~ /<lsf_login07>/)){
  val=val?val OFS $0:$0
}
'   Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
<594711> <RUN> <AL_Ptime> <lsf_login07> </shsv/DASA>
<594712> <RUN> <AL_Ptime> <lsf_login07> </shsv/CXZC>
```

***EDIT:*** Adding explanation for code here too.

```
awk '
/<\/shsv\/[a-zA-Z]+>/{   ##Search for string shsv with alphabets till their group in a line, then do following.
  val=val?val OFS $0:$0; ##create variable named val whose value is current line when val is NULL else it will concatenating its own value with each line.
  print val;             ##printing variable val here.
  flag="";               ##making variable flag as NULL here.
  next                   ##Using next will skip all statements further.
}
/<[0-9]+>/{              ##Search <digits till group and if it is TRUE then do following.
  flag=1;                ##Setting variable flag to 1 now.
  val=$0;                ##making variable val as current line.
  next                   ##Using next will skip all statements further.
}
val && (($0 ~ /<RUN>/) || ($0 ~ /<AL_Ptime>/) || ($0 ~ /<lsf_login07>/)){ ##Checking if variable val is NOT NULL AND (either current line is string <RUN> OR <AL_Ptime> OR <lsf_login07>) then do following.
  val=val?val OFS $0:$0  ##create variable named val whose value is value of current line if va; is NULL else it will concatenate its own value with current line.
}
' Input_file            ##Mentioning the Input_file name here.
```

Comment: can you explain me the line val=val?val OFS $0:$0 
and the input maybe change at <RUN> <Al_Ptime>

Comment: @Lucil120, I have added explanation for same too now. Kindly do let me know if you have any queries on same.